# Cant integrate mobx to simple flutter app that increments the counter on click

Tags: flutter, mobx

I'm new to flutter and can't resolve the issue.

Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be established.
    The following Dart file:
      /Users/anirudhsharma392/Desktop/flutter/testing/lib/counter/counter.dart
    ...refers, in an import, to the following library:
      /Users/anirudhsharma392/Desktop/flutter/testing/lib/counter/counter.g.dart
    Unfortunately, that library does not appear to exist on your file system.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mobx/flutter_mobx.dart';
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';

part 'counter.g.dart';

class Counter = CounterBase with _$Counter;

abstract class CounterBase implements Store {
  @observable
  int value = 0;

  @action
  void increment() {
    value++;
  }
}

class CounterExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CounterExampleState createState() => _CounterExampleState();
}

class _CounterExampleState extends State<CounterExample> {
  final _counter = Counter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Counter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Observer(
                  builder: (_) => Text(
                        '${_counter.value}',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _counter.increment,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mobx use code-generation to work. You need to run another command to generate the files needed for Mobx to work

There are two ways to generate these files:

- `flutter pub pub run build_runner build`
- `flutter pub pub run build_runner watch`

The former is a one-time generation. While the latter continuously watch your sources to update the generated files when an update is needed

Be sure to add `build_runner` to your dependencies:

```
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.1.2
```